# How to add property to object? (Cannot add property x, object is not extensible at x)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React and trying to add isCheck property to object.
this is my code.

```
const handleClickOpen = (element: ModalData) => {
    for (let i in element.symptoms) {
      if (element.symptoms[i].isCheck === true) {
        console.log('true');
      } else {
        element.symptoms[i].isCheck = false;
      }
    }
  };
```

but this error showing up

```
Cannot add property isCheck, object is not extensible at handleClickOpen
```

Is there any other way to add isCheck property?

Thank you.

Comment: try `console.log(Object.isFrozen(element.symptoms[i]))`  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Answer (score -1):

you should use below

'this.setState({

})'